# Will JYC IR Remote Controls ML-N work with a Nikon D7000?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, nikon-d7000, remote, shutter-release

I am searching for a remote control for my Nikon D7000.

I've found the [JYC IR Remote Controls ML-N](http://www.dinodirect.com/Nikon-D5000-D90-D80-D70s-D60-D50-D40-Remote-Control.html?cur=INR&AFFID=3111), but that site doesn't list the Nikon D7000 as a supported model.

I thought that the D90, D5000 and D7000 all use the same remote sensor, and a remote control can trigger any of them. Does the D7000 have a different remote sensor and thus require a different remote control? Or has that site just got the information wrong, and that remote can trigger a D7000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IR remote control ML-L3 Nikon I bought for my D90 works as well for my D7000.

Comment: So, they should have the same remote sensor. Thank you for your response :)